# How to find out if a button with an unknown ID is pressed php

Tags: php, mysql

Would anyone be able to help me with the following code...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dateTime";
$sqldata=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die( 'Error Retrieving data');
echo"<form>";
$var=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            var++; 
            echo"<fieldset>
            <legend>"; echo $row['Name']; echo"</legend>";
                echo"<table style='width:100%'>                     
                    <tr>
                        <td>Location</td>
                        <td>"; 
                        echo $row['EventLocation']; echo"</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Subject</td>
                        <td>"; 
                        echo $row['eventSubject']; echo"</td>  

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>"; 
                        echo $row['EventDescription']; echo"</td> 

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>"; 
                        echo $row['dateTime']; echo"</td> 
                    </tr>                                                           
            </table> <br>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Sign Me Up!' name='btnSignUp'></input>           
        </fieldset> <br>";
        }

echo"</form>";
```

When I loop through my while loop, a button will be created for each record in my table, then when the button is clicked, a user will sign up for an event. However, I am not sure how to check which button has been clicked? I normally do it like this...

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnSignUp']))
{
    $insert="INSERT INTO tblEventGuests (fkEvent, fkUser) VALUES ('". $row['pkEvent'] . "', '".$_SESSION['user']."'";

    if ($conn->query($insert) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "You have successfully signed up to this event";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

But because I am not sure of the name of the button or how many events there are (while coding) I have no clue how to go about doing what I need to do. Does anyone have any suggestions? Or even an alternative method? Thanks!

Comment: When you create the buttons create a hidden form element with them containing the data particular to that button.

Comment: First of all, `<form>` defaults to a GET method if POST isn't implied, and you're using POST arrays and that will fail *miserably & silently*. So your query will never happen.

Comment: @JayBlanchard All the hidden fields will be submitted, so how will that indicate which button was clicked?

Comment: Drat @Barmar, I thought there was a form for each row. I can see now that I was incorrect. When the OP said, *" a button will be created for each record in my table"* I made some assumptions.

Comment: and no idea if the session was even started. Probably irrelevant.

Comment: @JayBlanchard If I add a hidden element, how will I know what to put into this line if(isset($_POST['btnSignUp'])) because I will be unaware of any names of events, or the amount of events in the database if that makes sense? Sorry Im only new to php if this is a silly question

Comment: @Anon you need a form for each row and a button for each form.

Comment: to answers given below.... you missed something very important as outlined in my first comment to the OP

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know form should have that, totally forgot to add that part, I was more concerned with my buttons to notice! why will my POST fail? Sorry I'm  not used to PHP, I am using sessions, but more for if a user is logged in etc.

Comment: your code as I said would fail *silently* not giving form a post method. `<form>` is the equivalent to `<form method="get">` and action "self".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, OK I have fixed it now, so the form not knows its posting not getting!

Comment: Exactly. PHP made it that way and personally, think it's a form of a flaw in their original core design. Oh well, what can you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<input type="submit">`, use `<button type="submit">`. This will allow you to give the button a different label than the value, and the value will indicate which submit button they clicked on.

```
<button type='submit' name='btnSignup' value='{$row['eventId']}'>Sign me up!</button>
```

Then in the PHP that processes the form you can use the value of `$_POST['btnSignup']` to know which event they signed up for.

Answer (score 1):

Create the form *inside* the loop instead of *outside* it.  That way each form would individually contain exactly the information the server needs, instead of sending *everything* to the server and trying to figure out which subset of information was actually being selected.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    //...
    echo "<form method='POST'>
          <table style='width:100%'>                     
            <tr>
              <td>Location</td>
              <td>"; 
    echo $row['EventLocation'];
    echo "    </td> 
            </tr>
            <!--- etc... --->
          </table><br>
        </form>
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Sign Me Up!' name='btnSignUp'></input>           
    </fieldset> <br>";
}
```

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in [a comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900287/how-to-find-out-if-a-button-with-an-unknown-id-is-pressed-php#comment59461183_35900287), you also would need to define the `method` attribute on the form if you expect the values to be in the `$_POST` collection.  Note the updated code above.